# Class method instantiates another class while passing its self as an argument

Tags: python-3.x, classes

I have the following code. I have made a complicated approach to calculate apple's price. Thus, I put this approach in a separate class called `PriceUtl`. The code below is an simplification. I want the user of the `Apple` code can just call `apple.set_price(new_price)` to set the price of `apple`. Thus, I made a method `set_price` in the class `Apple`. However, the `PriceUtl` needs an instance of `Apple` (suppose it must need). Therefore, I called `PriceUtl` within the class of `Apple` and pass `self` to it.

This code works, but is it a good or safe way? Because I have never done this before. If I pass `self`, then the method `set_price` is also passed to `PriceUtl`, but `set_price` is calling `PriceUtl`.

Could you please help me?

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'red'
        self.wegiht = 5
        self.price = 0

    def set_price(self, new_price):
        utl = PriceUtl(apple=self, new_price=new_price)  # pass self to another class PriceUtl
        utl.run()


class PriceUtl:
    def __init__(self, apple: Apple, new_price: float):
        self._apple = apple
        self._new_price = new_price

    def run(self):
        self._apple.price = self._new_price


an_apple = Apple()
an_apple.set_price(new_price=10)
print(f'{an_apple.price = }')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for your comments. I have just revised it.

Comment: It still doesn't say what the _purpose_ is. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TobySpeight, thanks, my bad. Revised again.

Comment: We cannot review simplified examples. Please post your real code.

Comment: @Reinderien, sorry I did not know this. Then I will delete my post.

Answer (score 2):

This seems overkill.

We never use `Apple.wegiht` or `Apple.color`, so those assignments can be removed.

I don't see any need for the `PriceUtl` class at all - `Apple.set_price` can set its own member directly.

It's always good practice to use a *main guard* when writing programs, to make it easier to reuse their parts.

---

## Simplified code

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = 0

    def set_price(self, new_price):
        self.price = new_price

if __name__ == '__main__':
    an_apple = Apple()
    an_apple.set_price(new_price=10)
    print(f'{an_apple.price = }')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, as I described I got a real complicated approach to calculate price. So I separate this approach in class `PriceUtl`. The code here is an simplified example. So I have to use `PriceUtl`.

Comment: No, you clearly don't need to use `PriceUtl`, as this answer demonstrates.  If you've shown us something that's not [actual code from a project](/help/on-topic) then you've been wasting our time and you need to fix or remove your question.

Comment: Sorry, I will delete it.